# Create custom webpart that uses CAML Query

Tags: web-part, caml-query

I am quite new to Sharepoint and I am supposed to create a webpart that can display all the titles with a specific value from a managed metadata column(TAGS). I am required to write a CAML Query to probably return a list of documents that contains the TAGS value from the managed metadata column from a Document Library. Can I have some pointers to how am I supposed to deal with this? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below might help...Example is for Task list, but will work with any list type.

Suppose column name is ManagedMetadataColumn in you Task list and value you wanted to query by is 'My Value'

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
         {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
               // Build a query.
               SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
               query.Query = string.Concat(
                              "<Where><Eq>",
                                 "<FieldRef Name='ManagedMetadataColumn'/>",
                                 "<Value Type='TaxonomyFieldType'>My Value</Value>",
                              "</Eq></Where>",
                              "<OrderBy>",
                                 "<FieldRef Name='DueDate' Ascending='TRUE' />",
                                 "<FieldRef Name=’Priority’ Ascending='TRUE' />", 
                              "</OrderBy>");                    

               query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                                   "<FieldRef Name='ManagedMetadataColumn' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='DueDate' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='Priority' />");

               query.ViewFieldsOnly = true; // Fetch only the data that we need.

               // Get data from a list.
               string listUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/tasks";
               SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
               SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

               // Print a report header.
               Console.WriteLine("{0,-25}  {1,-20}  {2,-25}  {3}",
                  "ManagedMetadataColumn", "Task", "Due Date", "Priority");

               // Print the details.
               foreach (SPListItem item in items)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("{0,-25}  {1,-20}  {2,-25}  {3}",
                     item["AssignedTo"], item["LinkTitle"], item["DueDate"], item["Priority"]);
               }
            }
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope this helps.... Happy coding!!!

Comment: // Get data from a list.
               string listUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/tasks";
               SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
               SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

So i can change this portion to a code where I retrieve data from my document library?

Comment: true....also change all the columns names according to your library.....

Comment: Noted sir, i will try. Do i implement these codes in my feature's event receiver or somewhere else?

Comment: You said you need this in custom Webpart right ? Above code is Sever object model..it will work anywhere if correct dll are being referred

Comment: Sir, so would u recommend me to put them in my webpart.xml , webpart.cs, or webpart.webpart file? Sorry i am really new to sharepoint especially webparts so do pardon my mistakes.

Comment: it should be webpart.cs... it seems SharePoint very new to you, I would suggest you to please make sure you understand basics of SharePoint customization....what/when/why to be used for your customization..I can provide guidance if you are interested...

Comment: Sir, thanks for the code above. It worked perfectly when I tested it out in caml query helper. But i will require another favour from u.. which is to create a web part property for the value that I am trying to query.. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: no problem...please upvote and mark it answer for other's reference...

Comment: for webpart property.. try this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-add-custom-properties-in-visual-webpart or this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-webpart-properties

Comment: Sir my current requirement is to display the titles of the documents that contains the specific metadata value, for e.g "ABC". So i have to display the titles of the documents that uses the metadata tag "ABC" in the webpart. So my idea is to key in the value "ABC" when i am editing the webpart and then display the results from the CAML query onto a label/text box on my webpart. May I know if that is possible?

Comment: yes...this is possible... in that case, you webpart propeties has to be dynamic...populate it with all the managed metadata values by querying term store...then you can use this in your caml query... or alternatively if you want you can just have plain textbox so user will enter value of Tags.

Comment: After i key in the value "ABC" when I am editing my webpart, I get an error when i press "Apply"

Comment: please provide error details

Comment: Number of documents: An error has occurred. Number of documents is my webdisplayname.

Comment: It is not only for this property, but when i try to edit something else such as my Title of webpart, it shows the same error too

Comment: Please open new thread, paste screenshot and code for wepart properties

Comment: Created a new one sir, do view it thanks